# Plot a representative subset of countries in ggplot (panel dataset)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, sample

I have a panel dataset of 66 countries (grouped in 4 geographic zones) and 16 years.

I would like to plot the trend overtime of my dependent variable (FDI net flow), but since I have too many countries I would like to display only a representative sample of the countries. Equivalently I would like to exclude some countries or plot only countries with the highest FDI and the countries with the lowest FDI).

Do you know how can I do it?

This is my database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85Qmj.png)
I already tried some of this codes to exclude some countries but they don't work (and I would prefer to directly create a subset)

```
graph <- ggplot(data = na.omit(compdata), aes(x = time, y = lnfdinet, group = country), na.rm=TRUE) 
graph + geom_line(na.rm = TRUE) + aes(color=namegeozone)
graph %+% subset(compdata, country %in% c("ALB"))
```

or

```
ggplot(data=compdata, aes(time, lnfdinet, group=country, colour=country)) + geom_line(data=function(x){x[!x$country %in% c("ALB", "ARG"), ]}, alpha=0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not subset data prior to plotting.?

Something like

```
Dt=subset(compdata, country %in% c("ALB"))
```

And pass dt into `ggplot`

Once a `ggplot` is made , since the object is no longer a dataframe the subsetting logic as applied doesn't work.